# getting device id in android

Tags: android, imei, deviceid

I have found two ways to get device id in android but I do not which one of them better and what are the differences between them

**Method 1**

```
public static String getDeviceId2(Context context) {


        String androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(
                context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

        return androidId;
    }
```

**Method 2**

```
public static String getDeviceId(Context context) {

        if (PermissionManager.getInstance().hasSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == true) {

            return ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getDeviceId();
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does anyone know a work around for this warning on method 1? - Using these device identifiers is not recommended other than for high value fraud prevention and advanced telephony use-cases. For advertising use-cases, use AdvertisingIdClient$Info#getId and for analytics, use InstanceId#getId.

Answer (score 2):

`ANDROID_ID`

Can change. In 8.0 it changes upon reinstall of your app

> On Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher versions of the platform, a
>   64-bit number (expressed as a hexadecimal string), unique to each
>   combination of app-signing key, user, and device. Values of ANDROID_ID
>   are scoped by signing key and user. The value may change if a factory
>   reset is performed on the device or if an APK signing key changes. For
>   more information about how the platform handles ANDROID_ID in Android
>   8.0 (API level 26) and higher, see Android 8.0 Behavior Changes.
>
> Note: For apps that were installed prior to updating the device to a
>   version of Android 8.0 (API level 26) or higher, the value of
>   ANDROID_ID changes if the app is uninstalled and then reinstalled
>   after the OTA. To preserve values across uninstalls after an OTA to
>   Android 8.0 or higher, developers can use Key/Value Backup.

`getDeviceId()`

Is deprecated in 8.0

Answer (score 1):

First method is the right one. Second won't work on devices without sim cards